# Java compile Error when running a Hadoop map reducer

Tags: java, hadoop

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /Users/csstudent/Downloads/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.1.1.jar

Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.security.client.ClientHSSecurityInfo not in module
```

Comment: if you read the exception it seems that a class is not available

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop requires Java 8.

The fact that the error says something about modules means you're running Java 9 or higher